# Problemas com eventos no JS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estou fazendo um evento em js, mas o mesmo não está funcionando corretamente pelo seguinte fato se o usuário não selecionar pelo menos um rádio ele não acionar o evento, como faria para que o evento funcionasse como rádio tivesse em  checked ??

```html
<div class="radios-group">
<label>Forma de pagamento:</label><br>

                                  <?php if ($dados->atendimento_anotacoes <> null) {?>
                                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                        <input type="radio" id="dinheiro" name="forma-de-pagamento"
                                               class="custom-control-input" checked>
                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="dinheiro">Dinheiro</label>
                                    </div>

                                   <?php }else{ ?>
                                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                        <input type="radio" id="cartao_debito" name="forma-de-pagamento"
                                               class="custom-control-input" checked>
                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="cartao_debito">Cartão Débito</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                        <input type="radio" id="cartao_credito" name="forma-de-pagamento"
                                               class="custom-control-input">
                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="cartao_credito">Cartão Crédito</label>
                                    </div>


                                  <?php } ?>

                                </div>
```

```js
$(function () {

         $('.radios-group').find('input:radio').click(function () {

        var url = this.id;



        $(this).closest('form').prop('action', 'process/' + url + '.php');

    });

});
```

Comment: Se vc n explicar melhor não tem como ajudar, não entendi o que você quer fazer.

Answer (score 0):

Tens os dois botões radio com o atributo `checked` tenta retirar um deles.

```
<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
<input type="radio" id="dinheiro" name="forma-de-pagamento"
class="custom-control-input" checked>
<label class="custom-control-label" for="dinheiro">Dinheiro</label>
</div>


<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
<input type="radio" id="cartao_debito" name="forma-de-pagamento"nclass="custom-control-input">
<label class="custom-control-label" for="cartao_debito">Cartão Débito</label>
</div>
```